# List comprehension TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

The following list comprehension returns `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`.

```
new_list = [re.sub(r'in_content_1', r'in_content_2', i) for i in foo_list if re.findall(r'content_name', i, re.M) not in i]
```

What is the correct way to use re.sub and conditioned re.findall in a list comprehension?

Comment: Please do not name lists `list` in python, it is bad practice and overrides a builtin python name.  Can you post what is in `list` however?

Comment: @chrisz The issue is that `re.findall(r'content_name', i, re.M)` is a list, not `i`.

Comment: Yep, my mistake.

Comment: @faber Depending on what you want to do (*which is not entirely clear to me*) you probably need `any()` or `all()`. Example: `... if any(x in i for x in re.findall(r'content_name', i, re.M))]`

Comment: You can use `re.search()` to check if it exists in `i` instead of `re.findall()`.

Comment: The error message is misleading because it's incomplete. It should be: `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list` (notice the `<string>` part).

Comment: @all thanks for answering so fast. Will elaborate more my request and update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns a `list` of all the matches. If none are found, it'll return an empty `list`, and hence will always be a `list`. So, the part `if re.finall(...) not in i` evaluates to `if <list> not in <string>` which is why you are seeing the error.

You can use `re.search()` to do the same thing you want.

```
new_list = [re.sub(r'in_content_1', r'in_content_2', i) for i in foo_list if not re.search(r'content_name', i, re.M)]
```

Comment: Keyur, thank you :). "if not re.search" solved it easily. I tried also with "if not re.findall" and it works too.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. `if not re.findall()` will work too, if the string doesn't contain the required text, the list will be empty (as I said above) and will evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the if statement; in fact the

```
re.findall(r'content_name', i, re.M)
```

return a list of "content_name" founded in the **i** variable. You could change the line in:

```
new_list = [re.sub(r'in_content_1', r'in_content_2', i) for i in old_list if 'content_name' not in i]
```

as suggested by @chrisz I changed the name *list* in *old_list*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed with if 'content_name' it works, but I need to use a regex to match 'content_name'

Comment: I can’t understand: if content_name is a fixed string you don’t need to use a regex; otherwise if you need to search for a specific pattern a regex is good choose.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear enough. I needed a regex to match a specific pattern that I can't match with a fixed string.